# Kue not working on events properly?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kue

I have the following codes for sending mail on `kue`

```
require('dotenv').load();
const mailer = require('../helper/mailer');
const kue = require('kue'),
  queue   = kue.createQueue();

console.log("Starting server");
queue.process('email',function(job,done){
  console.log(job.data);
  mailer
    .prepareContext(job.data)
    .then(mailer.prepareBody)
    .then(mailer.prepareMail)
    .then(mailer.sendMail)
    .then((data)=>{
      console.log("Mail sent");
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err.message);
    });
});

queue.on('error',(err)=>{
  console.log(err);
});
```

The problem is it only responds on first event. I have to restart the script to send another one. Am i doing something wrong here ?

I am adding events using

```
helper.sendVerificationMail = function(data){
  return new Promise(function(fullfill,reject){
    try{
      var ctx = {};
      ctx.from = "account";
      ctx.to_email = data.email;
      ctx.subject = "Verifiy your email address";
      ctx.template = "signup";
      ctx.ctx = {};
      ctx.ctx.verification = data.verification;
      queue.create('email',ctx).save();
      fullfill(data);
    }catch(err){
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the documentation:
[Processing Concurrency](https://github.com/Automattic/kue)
Processing Concurrency

By default a call to queue.process() will only accept one job at a time for processing. For small tasks like sending emails this is not ideal, so we may specify the maximum active jobs for this type by passing a number:

```
queue.process('email', 20, function(job, done){
  // ...
});
```